# How do I display certain text for blank results in a column. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm needing to display the words "None provided" for any customers that did not give a second address. What would I use to only provide the address2 column with those words where the return is blank?

```
/* Create a customer list that shows the customer name, address, second address (if the customer does not list a second address, print out "none provided") 
and postal code. */

SELECT CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) AS Name,
CONCAT(address.address,",",address.address2,",",postal_code) AS Customer_info
FROM customer
INNER JOIN address
ON customer.address_id = address.address_id;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `IF()` function

```
CONCAT(address.address, ',', IF(address.address2 != '', address.address2, 'None provided'), ",", postal_code) AS Customer_info
```

Comment: We need to check for null as well.

Comment: I've inverted the test so it should work for both null and blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` to solve your problem.

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) AS Name,
CASE 
 when address = '' OR andress IS NULL then 
 "None provided"
 when address <> ''then
 CONCAT(address.address,",",address.address2,",",postal_code)
END AS Customer_info
FROM customer
INNER JOIN address
ON customer.address_id = address.address_id;
```